# Angular Login form lets me through with any username & password pair

Tags: angular

My problem is that i have a username & password pair to login a user, but instead of only this one should work my login form accepts any kind of username - password pair, even empty fields and let me go to the protected page. If i send my credentials with postman it works as expected so the problem should be on the frontend side.

here is my login component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../service/AuthServices/authentication.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username = '';
  password = '';
  invalidLogin = false;
  error = '';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private loginservice: AuthenticationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  checkLogin() {
    (this.loginservice.authenticate(this.username, this.password)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // debugger;
          this.router.navigate(['employee'])

          this.invalidLogin = false
          console.log('User is logged in');
        },
        error => {
          this.error = error;
          console.log('error');
          this.invalidLogin = true
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my service for login:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  public currentUser: Observable<any>;

  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/test/rest/employees/' 

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): any {    //:User
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let url = this.baseUrl + 'login';
    const data = {
      username,
      password
    };

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, data, { headers }).pipe(
      map(user => {
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        return user;
      })
    );
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    return !(user === null)
  }

  logOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: `checkLogin` looks suspicious, how is it begin used?

Comment: what is returned by your post request if the credentials given are incorrect? 
Also there is no need to use `.pipe(first())` with a REST request as there should only be one response.

Comment: it sends back an error message telling me that the authentication of the user failed,but still logs in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing an AuthGuard

https://codeburst.io/using-angular-route-guard-for-securing-routes-eabf5b86b4d1

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro after implementing an Authguard solved my problem, though without passing any credentials it still logs in but that's probably because the problem Darksilence pointed out

Comment: my pleasure @Kerk

Answer (score 2):

Multiple things
1) Authenticate method has no checks whether its empty or you really have a user. So for example if your backend service return empty string when user is not authenticate, you basically setting that locally and then returning that as a value for your checkLogin.

2)checklogin not even checking whether its a success or not and you are redirecting it to the page. so what you need is check to see whether its a success or not at checkLogin before redirecting